# error in converting word document to pdf using iText

Tags: java, pdf, itext

The below is the code that i used to convert a word document to pdf. After compiling the code, the PDF file is generated. But the file contains some junk characters along with the word document content. Please help me to know what modification should i do to get rid of the junk characters.
The code i used is:

```
import com.lowagie.text.Document; 
import com.lowagie.text.Paragraph; 
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter; 
import java.io.File; 
import java.io.FileOutputStream; 



public class PdfConverter 
{

    private void createPdf(String inputFile, String outputFile)//, boolean isPictureFile) 
    {
        Document pdfDocument = new Document(); 
        String pdfFilePath = outputFile; 
        try
        {
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(pdfFilePath); 
            PdfWriter writer = null; 
            writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(pdfDocument, fileOutputStream); 
            writer.open(); 
            pdfDocument.open(); 
            /*if (isPictureFile) 
            { 
            pdfDocument.add(com.lowagie.text.Image.getInstance(inputFile)); 
                } 
            else 
            { */
            File file = new File(inputFile); 
    pdfDocument.add(new Paragraph(org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToString(file))); 
                //} 
            pdfDocument.close(); 
            writer.close(); 
            System.out.println("PDF has been generted"); 
            } 
            catch (Exception exception) 
            { 
            System.out.println("Document Exception!" + exception); 
            } 
            } 

    public static void main(String args[]) 
    { 
    PdfConverter pdfConversion = new PdfConverter(); 
    pdfConversion.createPdf("C:/test.doc", "C:/test.pdf");//, true); 

        }

    }
```

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 2):

Only because you name your class PdfConverter you don't have one. All you do is reading the binary content as a String and writing this as one paragraph (and that's what you see). This approach will definitively not be successful. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437394 for a similar question.

If you are interested just in the content of your word document, you might want to give [Apache POI - the Java API for Microsoft Documents](http://poi.apache.org) a try to read your the document not at binary level but on a hight abstraction level. If your Word document has a simple (and I mean a *really* simple) structure you might get reasonable results.

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you will have to read the doc file correctly and then use the read data to create the PDF file.

What you are doing right now is that you are reading data from doc file, which is having garbage values since you are not using proper API to read the data, and then storing the obtained garbage data in the PDF file. Hence the issue.